# How can I generate an English alphabet and number image with Matlab

Tags: matlab

I want to generate an artificial image that contains all the English alphabets as well as numbers (from 0 to 9) with Matlab, and the final image I expect looks like:

```
A  B  C  D
E  F  G  H
....
1  2  3  4
...
6  7  8  9
```

The image will be gray scale, and all the characters would be set 0 while the background is set 100. Any ideas on how to generate this image?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use characters (e.g. `'A'`) just like numbers, so to create an array containing all uppercase letters, you can call `'A':'Z'`. The same goes with numbers: `'1':'9'` (note the quotation marks, so these are characters, not numbers!). You can do some [`reshape`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/reshape.html) magic to get them aligned as you like:

```
x = [reshape(['A':'Z',' ',' '],4,[]).' ; reshape(['1':'9',' ',' ',' '],4,[]).']
```

<sub>Yes, this is an ugly hack, manually adding the spaces.</sub>

Now you can place this string `x` in a figure window using the [`text`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) function. Using a monospace font produces much nicer results. You can style the text using all the options in the linked help page.

```
text(0.5,0.5,x,'FontName','FixedWidth')
```

And finally, after turning off the axes, you can use the [`getframe`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/getframe.html) function to print the figure into an image.

```
axis off
im = getframe(gcf);
```

[image: result]

Sorry, this is not with `background=100` and `characters=0`, but you should easily be able to crop, scale and style the image using the properties of [`text`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html), [`axis`](http://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/axis.html) and some manual scaling on the matrix. With a larger font size, the text will also be less pixelated.